# Any popular Rails tricks for keeping a nav's css selected when flipping through partials?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, css, select, uinavigationcontroller

I have an admin with a nav. The nav toggles between different partials.

The nav has several `li`'s, and when one of them is selected, it gets the `.selected` class that makes it highlighed.

Is there anyway to toggle this from the controller? Or any other place that's popular among Rubyists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%ul
  -@links.each do |link|
    %li= link_to_unless_current(link.title, link){link.title, link, :class => "selected"}
```

link_to_unless_current takes a block which is the block to render if it is current.

Answer (score 1):

Use gem `simple-navigation`. It solves this and many other problems.

[Link to GitHub](http://wiki.github.com/andi/simple-navigation/)

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen a standard solution for this, but the helper [current_page?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M002148) may be the answer.